# entering text in a textarea with fixed position scrolls down the containing container in chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome

**this behavior happens only in chrome (i'm using version 41.0.2272.118).
it doesn't happen in Canary.**
i still want a work around if there is any.

you can see it in action in [this pen](http://codepen.io/avipinto/pen/ogKpPe)
enter text(including Enter) at the textarea and see how the div scrolls,
but if you change the style of the form to have bottom:150px instead of 0 (this causes the textarea to be on top of the div) , it won't scroll the div.

here is the structure:

```
<div class="pageCont">
  <div class="cont">
    <div class="innerCont">
       <div>Item 1</div>
       <div>Item 2</div>
       <div>Item 3</div>
       <div>and a lot more of these</div>
    </div>
    <form action="">
      <textarea name="" id="" cols="30" rows="5"></textarea> 
    </form>
  </div>  
</div>
```

and the css:

```
html {box-sizing: border-box;}
*, *:before, *:after {box-sizing: inherit;}
.pageCont{
  height:300px;
  padding-bottom:90px;
}
.cont{
  overflow: auto;
  height:100%;
  width:300px;

}
.innerCont{
  position:relative;
}
form
{
  position:fixed;
  bottom:0;
  //bottom:150px;
  width:100%;
  //top:50px; //doesn't happen in this case
}
textarea{
  dosplay:block;
  width:100%;
  height:80px;
}
```

Comment: This is really strange behaviour and most likely a bug in chrome, I'm curious if someone has a more complete answer to this.

Comment: Interesting. Confirmed in my Chrome 41.0.2272.118 (64-bit) Linux.

Comment: just updated chrome, happens also in 42.0.2311.90 m

Comment: Well i think i would take the textarea out from that container, as you don't need it there for layout reasons and maybe put hidden input instead and update it with js on textarea change

Comment: Bnaya, this is a constraint i have because of layout reasons, the above example is a stripped down version of what i have. if this was also a bug in Canary i might change the layout, but it will be fixed two chrome versions from now, i just want a workaround if there is any.

Comment: Well, horribly hard to implement thing will be to swallow the keypress event (e.preventDefault) and apply the key function using js. maybe wysiwyg editors are already doing that.
Another options, layout the element using js. I don't have any real good solution

Comment: I guess, it would not help to prevent keypress events. The _form_ and the _innercont_ are within a scrollable _cont_ div. For any keypress, after 1 letter even arrow keys behave like that, Chrome seems to scroll to the "assumed position!?" of the form, until it is visible in the scrollable div. @avi-pinto: the value of 150px bottom depends on the screen size. In fact what seems to count is "that textarea to be on top of the div", or more exactly directly visible in the scrollable area.

Comment: preventing keypress does prevent it but then you have to do ugly tricks to get the text into the textarea(not the way i want to go). the 150px was supposed to put the div visible in the scrollable area, the funny thing is that it has to be 100% inside it, if even 1 pixel is outside of the scrollable area, the behavior will happen

Answer (score 1):

Very strange, but I may have a fix.

I found that by moving the `form` outside of `div.innerCont` it stopped the scrolling behavior, so all I can figure is that since it was inside, the browser was trying to scroll to the bottom of `div.cont` to show. See the updated pen here: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/XbWaLW

Obviously something buggy as `position:fixed` should remove the element from the normal flow of the page, but hope this can help.

Comment: you moved it outside of cont, unfortunately this is a constraint i have